# Modifying output for the distinguishedName in Get-ADComputer

Tags: powershell

I'm pretty basic in my powershell knowledge. Anyway i'm trying to make a script that will convert the output from the distinguishedName in a Get-ADComputer.

I normal case the result from querying the server with the Get-ADComputer the distinguishedName looks like this depending how the OU's is structured:

```
CN=<servername>,OU=Others,OU=Servers,OU=0180,DC=win,DC=dom,DC=<something>,DC=com
```

What I want to do is to convert the output into two columns and re-organize the information. So far I have got the part with two columns sorted as shown below.

> Name   ParentContainer
>   -------  ---------------
>   server1   OU=Others,OU=Servers,OU=0180,DC=win,DC=dom,DC=,DC=com
>   server2   OU=DRA8,OU=Servers,OU=Admins,DC=win,DC=dom,DC=,DC=com
>   server3   OU=Others,OU=Servers,OU=0180,DC=win,DC=dom,DC=,DC=com
>   server4   OU=Others,OU=Servers,OU=0180,DC=win,DC=dom,DC=,DC=com
>   server5   OU=Servers,OU=4611,DC=win,DC=dom,DC=,DC=com

the script looks like this:

```
$list = Get-Content "C:\temp\testservers.txt"
foreach ($servers in $list)
{
Get-ADcomputer "$servers" -Properties distinguishedName,cn | 
select name, @{n='ParentContainer';e={$_.distinguishedname -replace '^.+?,(CN|OU.+)','$1'}}
}
```

Now to the tricky part. In the column "ParentContainer I would like to have all "DC=" values removed and then switch the OU around so instead of the above it should look like it below.

> Name   ParentContainer
>   -------  ---------------
>   server1   OU=0180,OU=Servers,OU=Others
>   server2   OU=Admins,OU=Servers,OU=DRA8
>   server3   OU=0180,OU=Servers,OU=Others
>   server4   OU=0180,OU=Servers,OU=Others
>   server5   OU=4611,OU=Servers

The reason for this is that it will be easier to see the OU structure and in which OU the server placed in and in a CSV file.

Is it possible to do or am I out on deep water?

Regards
Torbjorn Persson

Answer (score 4):

Give this a try. Split the DN, the first element gives you the server name. Then use the range operator to get all the other elements, top to bottom , that do not start with 'dc=' and join then back.:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * | ForEach-Object{

    $dn = $_.DistinguishedName.Split(',')

    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        Name = $dn[0] -replace '^cn='
        ParentContainer = $dn[$dn.length..1] -notlike 'dc=*' -join ','
    }

}
```

By the way, you might want to check the CanonicalName attribute. It may give you the output you're after in a similar manner without the need to manipulate the DN.

Comment: No problem, consider marking it as the answer if it met your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can write an inline code, but to make things easier, import the Format-OU function which I've written, then adjust your select line of code to:

```
select name, @{n='ParentContainer';e={Format-OU -OUString $_.distinguishedname}}
```

Format-OU Function:

```
Function Format-OU()
{
    param
    (
        [String]$OUString
    )
    $OUString = $OUString.Substring(0,$OUString.IndexOf("DC")-1)
    $OUArray = $OUString.Split(",")
    $Result = ""
    $Count = 1
    $OUArray | % {IF ($Count -eq 1) {$Result = $Result.Insert(0,"$_")} ELSE {$Result = $Result.Insert(0,"$_,")};$Count++}
    Return $Result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another possibility:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * | ForEach-Object{  
  $split = ($dn -split 'CN=|,DC=.+').split(',',2) 
  New-Object PSObject -property @{
   Name=$split[1];ParentContainer=$split[2]}
}
```